# Optional CaseIterable in swift?

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

For example:

```
enum Filter {
  case filter1
  case filter2
  ...
}

let allCases: [Filter?] = [.filter1, .filter2, ..., nil]
```

The problem is there are could be a lot of cases and `CaseIterable` returns `[Filter]` (nonoptional values only). How to solve this issue properly?

Comment: Why would you expect an array of optionals back? `CaseIterable` (which you aren't actually using!) returns a definite result depending on the enum cases.

Comment: Please provide a real use case, since with the current overly simplified example, this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @DávidPásztor The real case is when enum values represent "radio group items" on the screen. But you also have an item "None" or "All" which is not linked with any enum value and shouldn't be returned by `allCases` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your enum conform to `CaseIterable` you could easily create an array of optional values

```
enum Filter: CaseIterable {
  case filter1
  case filter2
}

let allCases: [Filter?] = Filter.allCases + [nil]
```

or add it as a computed property

```
extension Filter {
    var optionalValues: [Filter?] {
        Self.allCases + [nil]
    }
}
```

or as a computed property in `CaseIterable`

```
extension CaseIterable  {
    static var optionalValues: [Self?] {
        allCases.map(Optional.init) + CollectionOfOne(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I need to call `Filter.allCases.map { $0 as? Filter }`

Comment: additionally is it possible to write an extension for `CaseIterable` to add `optionalValues` to all enums?

Comment: `Self.` is redundant on an extension static property. Btw You should favor the use of CollectionOfOne when adding a single element collection.  `return` keyword can also be omitted. `allCases.map(Optional.init) + CollectionOfOne(nil)` or `(allCases as? [AllCases.Element?] ?? []) + CollectionOfOne(nil)` or simply `.init(allCases) + CollectionOfOne(nil)`

Comment: Note also that `AllCases.Element` is the same as `Self` therefore you can return `[Self?]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you. I think my edit contained everything from a brain fart (using return) to not knowing (CollectionOfOne) :)